# R function strange output

Tags: r, function, output

I have written a function as follows

```
simsim=function(n,model){
df=duplication
for(j in 2:(n+1)){
for(i in 3:(n_T-1)){
t_ip=df[i-2,j]
knownDensity=function(t_i){conDensity(t_i,t_ip,i,model)}
maxDensityValue <- optimise(knownDensity,lower=t_ip,upper=10,maximum=TRUE,tol=1e-10)[[2]]
df[i-1,j]=RejectionSampling(1)
}
}
return(df[,1:(n+1)])
}
```

which gives me undesirable output like this

```
       numberOfLineages     time1     time2
1                 2  0.000000  0.000000
2                 3  9.336734  9.234336
3                 4  9.168868  9.631127
4                 5  9.530523  9.496153
5                 6  9.836319  9.110507
6                 7  9.083733  9.770084
7                 8  9.215956  9.688086
8                 9  9.518183  9.100278
9                10  9.624247  9.323526
10               11  9.087299  9.890821
11               12  9.860937  9.177940
12               13  9.842235  9.307364
13               14  9.546416  9.190418
14               15  9.753121  9.499723
15               16  9.368431  9.107371
16               17  9.157236  9.112211
17               18  9.548059  9.199476
18               19  9.338566  9.185450
19               20  9.838453  9.403675
20               21  9.162214  9.324189
21               22  9.543628  9.081443
22               23  9.826989  9.676520
23               24  9.678934  9.754507
24               25  9.185565  9.461084
25               26  9.210276  9.240934
26               27  9.088698  9.596043
27               28  9.115626  9.316785
28               29  9.852018  9.503212
29               30  9.241426  9.130218
30               31  9.402581  9.356230
31               32 10.000000 10.000000
```

but as follows, when I execute the same code content not as a function, it works well!

```
n=2
model="subf"
df=duplication

for(j in 2:(n+1)){
for(i in 3:(n_T-1)){
t_ip=df[i-2,j]
knownDensity=function(t_i){conDensity(t_i,t_ip,i,model)}
maxDensityValue <- optimise(knownDensity,lower=t_ip,upper=10,maximum=TRUE,tol=1e-10)[[2]]
df[i-1,j]=RejectionSampling(1)
}
}
df[,1:(n+1)]
```

Output exactly as I want when not executed as a function. But I need to have it as a function for further programming. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. (As you can see a lot of self-defined functions are used, so I can't post them all.)

```
   numberOfLineages      time1     time2
1                 2  0.0000000  0.000000
2                 3  0.2400223  3.144337
3                 4  0.8822732  3.283141
4                 5  0.9518082  3.308656
5                 6  1.2382055  3.857698
6                 7  4.2428253  3.983578
7                 8  4.9173718  4.426273
8                 9  5.3208936  4.740513
9                10  5.5510037  5.610131
10               11  5.7879305  5.990622
11               12  5.9993579  6.060750
12               13  6.5851204  6.250583
13               14  6.7070604  6.267515
14               15  6.8405752  6.448780
15               16  7.2232624  6.601193
16               17  7.3051854  6.728651
17               18  7.7464502  7.030459
18               19  8.1031544  7.653167
19               20  8.2474993  7.858583
20               21  8.2991073  8.079234
21               22  8.6717877  8.135119
22               23  8.7701064  8.438933
23               24  8.9846576  8.778306
24               25  9.0557824  8.886325
25               26  9.1010022  9.333298
26               27  9.2070311  9.518253
27               28  9.4337597  9.602161
28               29  9.5508867  9.674323
29               30  9.6159529  9.675922
30               31  9.6615460  9.861703
31               32 10.0000000 10.000000
```

Comment: What does `df[i-1,j]=RejectionSampling(1)` do? Shouldn't it always give the same result if the only argument is a constant "1"?

Comment: In the code you say doesn't work (when you call it as a function) you are now showing your function call.  Can you confirm you are setting `n = 2` and `model = 'subf'`.  Also, you use `n_T` but that isn't set anywhere in the code you provided.  Have you also tried breaking the problem down to see at which line of code the values first differ between both methods ?

Comment: My guess is `RejectionSampling` is trying to access some objects that are defined only in the function block. These objects should be passed to `RejectionSampling` as arguments.

Comment: Exactly as @PhilippeMarchand said, this problem is stem from the RejectionSampling function. It calls the knownDensity and maxDensityValue in the function block. After I edited the code again, they are moved into the RejectionSampling and are correctly called. Thanks